# How do I pass in the path of GhostScript to iText7 CompareTool functionality?

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm attempting to visually compare pdf files using iText7 in C#. I'm unable to figure out how to tell iText7 where GhostScript is installed.

Environment variables on my machine are set.
In code i have also tried environment.setenvironmentvariable

> Message: iText.Kernel.Utils.CompareTool+CompareToolExecutionException : Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec= (e.g. -DgsExec="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")

Answer (score 1):

That message is a literal port of the Java version of iText, and is not literally applicable for C#.

If you look in [the source code of CompareTool.cs](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/utils/CompareTool.cs#L144), then you will see starting on line 144:

```
/// <summary>Creates an instance of the CompareTool.</summary>
public CompareTool() {
    gsExec = SystemUtil.GetEnvironmentVariable("gsExec");
    compareExec = SystemUtil.GetEnvironmentVariable("compareExec");
}
```

So, the exact environment variables you need to create, are not *`-DgsExec`* and *`-DcompareExec`*, but **`gsExec`** and **`compareExec`**. The *`-D`* prefix is just the Maven (build automation tool from the Java world) way of setting system properties on the commandline.

If you want, then you can [submit a pull request to iText 7 .NET](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/pulls) to fix the documentation. The file to change is `itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/utils/CompareTool.cs` and the lines to change are [72](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/utils/CompareTool.cs#L72) and [94](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/utils/CompareTool.cs#L94). Please read the [Contribution Guidelines](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md) before you start.

Comment: That's great! It obviously didn't even cross my mind to check the source code. I'll look to submit the pull request in the next few days as you mentioned.